# NDK Architecture

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an Android app with cpp ndk lib. the lib is based on an object named Main.
Main.cpp:

```
static Main * instance;
Java_my_package_MainService_initMain()
{
    instance = new Main(); //OK
}
```

The JAVA part of the app starts a service, the service init the Main cpp object and then starts an activity (I want the service to run in the background to do stuff while sometimes there is a UI for the user). When I'm calling the lib from the new activity the Main object is null.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Nahum

Comment: I figured up something: After the service starts the activity the garbage collector cleans it and unload the lib. So I guess the real question is, why does the service doesn't keep running?

Comment: That analysis is incorrect.  The garbage collector does not unload JNI libraries, in fact at present you cannot even explicitly unload them.  However, if the process terminates and is replaced, you might get a new process which has either never loaded the library, or which has loaded the library but never been told to initialize this static variable you seem to be trying to use as a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is a good solution, here is what I'm doing.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_my_package_MainService_initMain()
{
  Main *instance = new Main();
  return (int)instance;
}
```

I'm casting the object (an object is just a pointer) to an int and I return it to the java.
Then the java send the object to all JNI function.

Comment: This method looks like what I used

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep reference to create the java class that uses the NDK in a bit different way.

First create a Java class (let's call it Main), then link native function to an instance method (non-static).

Then call the native method from the constructor of Main.

Create a static reference somewhere else in your Java app and initialize it with "new Main();".

Now your reference is kept, so the java class can not be unloaded and thus the lib will not be unloaded either.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to implement calls to System.load in my Application class that extends 
android.app.Application.
It's an object guaranteed to be existing through out your applications life cycle.
That way there will be no unloading of dll's or reloading, which will cause an unnessecary overhead, of course.
And because the stack - handling (java- sided) is rather complex (remember the 
"android:launchMode" attribute which somewhat adresses this issue),
I choose to rather stay with the system dealing with this kind of dll - managment.